# Call keyboard on Event and send to Stream

Tags: flutter

I have a complex design for a text input field and its impossible to apply so many styles and effects on it. So i was thinking about to call (show/hide) the keyboard on a click event and send input data to a `Stream` and then display it with `Text()`. But i have no idea if it is possible to do it?

The problem is how to call a keyboard on gesturedetector. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: *"I have a complex design for a text input field and its impossible to apply so many styles and effects on it"* what do you mean by that?

Comment: prefix + input text + suffix + suffix and  they are all with different styles

Comment: you have `RichText` / `Text.rich` options for showing rich text

Comment: but i need to input data somehow too

Comment: i think i will do:
```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      focusNode: myFocusNode,
    );
  }
```

```
FloatingActionButton(
  // When the button is pressed, give focus to the text field using
  // myFocusNode.
  onPressed: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode),
);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773962/2252830