# Styling certain words inside an EditableText

Tags: flutter, formatting, rich-text-editor, flutter-widget

I'm new to flutter and I need an editor that can format certain words (e.g., automatic URL detection and formatting it to blue inside the editor). So far, I have not found a plugin for that so I decided to write my own plugin.

The question here is: where do I start?

I've tried using a `Rich.text()` with `TextSpan` as children but I can't edit those children. I've tried using a `SizedBox` with inside of it an `EditableText` but I encountered 2 problems.

- The `fontSize` of `EditableText` always differs from the `fontSize` of a `TextSpan`, no matter if I apply the same `TextStyle` (this really frustrates me)
- The whole `Rich.text()` doesn't work as a single editor, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Could someone point me into the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773962/2252830

Comment: Ok, I feel really stupid now, thanks a lot @pskink !

Comment: stupid? warum? errare humanum est ;-)

Comment: @pskink Of course. But I was looking for a solution, thinking I knew the way towards it and overcomplicating things :D

Comment: its like [Ockhams Rasiermesser](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ockhams_Rasiermesser) - "Wesenheiten dürfen nicht über das Notwendige hinaus vermehrt werden." ;-)

Comment: @pskink Thanks, that was an interesting read! I have a small question on the side. I can display whatever I want, inside one of those spans, however the cursor will still only behave as if the original text is there. Say, I replace every "2" with "22", the cursor will not "recognize" the second "2". Is there a way to create some sort of "placeholder" for this, so that the cursor behaves in a predictable way for a user?

Comment: post your somewhere, for example on https://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mMHpMTNsNK/
What I'm doing, is showing content that is actually longer than the actual text of the TextEditingController. If the text would be "123", the cursor would stay at the 3rd position and the visible `TextSpan`'s would show "112|233" (where | is the cursor). It doesn't 'see' the difference between what is visible for the user and what is in the `.text`. 

Why do I want that? I am thinking of displaying a thumbnail of an apple directly in front of the word, content that the TextField won't take into account when drawing the cursor.

Comment: good, i will take a look but most likely respond here next week

Comment: Thanks in advance! I have time, given current situation :\

Comment: hi, i checked sources of `EditableText ` and it seems that `TextEditingController` is used for styling only - if you need to change the entered text you should use `inputFormatters` - for more info see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_formatter.dart#L32 - there are 3 concrete classes that extend `TextInputFormatter`