# Is it possible to make RIchText Editable in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, text

I have a situtaion where i need to edit a richtext widget.
Im trying to design a compiler in flutter and syntax should be highlighted for it to be userfriendly. The syntax highlighting is working but im not able to edit the richtext. I'm just able to copy paste a code and the syntax is changing styles. I want to be able to edit the Text in RichText

Present Code

```
RichText(
            textScaleFactor: _baseFontScale,
            text: TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'monospace', fontSize: 12, height: 1.13),
              children: <TextSpan>[
                getSyntax(widget.syntax, widget.syntaxTheme).format(widget.code)
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Im currently using stack and placing another textfield in the same place to achieve this but its not going so good. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you would like to have `TextField` but styled with different styles per each word?

Comment: Yes @pskink
Is there a way?

Comment: override [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/buildTextSpan.html) method in a custom `TextEditingController`

Comment: I'm new to flutter. Could you please answer it briefly @pskink

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773962/2252830 - of course you dont need `splitMapJoin` - this is up to you how you construct your `TextSpan`

Answer (score 0):

see this package -- extended_text_field

Answer (score 0):

@pskink, You great answer must be an answer here too, not a comment:

It possible to colorize the TextField's content by overriding buildTextSpan method at used TextEditingController: see an example at pskink's answer in related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773962/2064459