# Build a code editor with syntax highlighter using TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-pub, code-editor

I am trying to build **Code Editor** in Flutter app using TextField, I tried using [flutter_syntax_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_syntax_view) but the problem is, it only accept code as a predefined string text and it does not have any option to write a code.

This is what I have tried:

- Used `TextField` with `maxLines` 10
- If we can show number of lines on left like code editor

Open for suggestions, appreciate the help

Comment: implement `TextEditingController.buildTextSpan`, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59773962/2252830

Comment: Hey, that will be for highlighting the syntax, how we can get number on left side like a code editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my work on github:
http://github.com/icedman/flutter_editor

It uses flutter_highlight, multicursor edits, minimap, line number gutter. Under development - you may want to contribute to that project.

I also wrote an article on creating an editor under 1000 lines of code in Flutter - wherein i explained why i ditched the textfield and made my own widget:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/build-a-text-editor-with-flutter-ui-under-1000-lines-of-code-5a9dd2a053da