# Calculating substring position in Flutter TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to draw an `OverlayEntry` over a part of the text of a TextField. Like in this screenshot. [image: iOS]

I am showing only the code to get the top offset position for the selected text, because this is where I have problems.

```dart
double getTextBoxTop(String selectedText) {
    TextStyle textStyle = widget.textStyle; 
    TextPainter painter = TextPainter(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      text: TextSpan(style: textStyle, text: controller.text),
    )..layout();
    double lineHeight = painter.preferredLineHeight;
    // on what line number the substring begins
    int lineNumber = getLineNumberForText(selectedText); 
    // offset of TextField from the top of the screen
    // focus node is attached to TextField
    double textFieldOffset = focusNode.offset.dy;
    // scroll controller attached to TextField
    double scrollOffset = scrollController.offset;

    return textFieldOffset +
    (lineHeight * lineNumber) +
    (lineHeight / 2) * lineNumber -
    scrollOffset;
}
```

This works perfectly, but only on iOS. No matter how far the TextField is scrolled, the overlay is always drawn over the selected text. On Android the top offset is never over the text I want.
[image: Android]
Tested on several Android devices, and on each device the offset is never the same, that is on some devices it is smaller, or bigger. I thought maybe it has something to do with the device pixel ratio, but on iOS it works on every device even iPads.

How can I get it working on Android, on every device? And shouldn't Flutter be device independent with this?

I also tried computing `LineMetrics` in the `TextPainter` and they are the same on iOS and Android.

Comment: btw the key method used is: [RenderEditable.getBoxesForSelection](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderEditable/getBoxesForSelection.html) so it should work as it uses `RenderEditable` object that directly draws your `TextField`

Comment: Awesome, seems to be working . Thanks a bunch. Want to write it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted? And do you have an example of how to get the RenderEditable from the render tree object?

Comment: It works with scrolling, I am not applying and ScrollController offsets and your code works even when scrolled several screens

Comment: check my edited answer, now it looks as it should... no stupid workarounds like in original version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is: use `RenderEditable.getBoxesForSelection`, but its not that easy to get it.

first you have to get the current `RenderObject` and call `visitChildren` on it inside `initState` method.

once the `_visitor` finds `RenderEditable` it is passed to `_FooTextFieldOverlayPainter` where it is used inside `paint` method, check it out:

```
class FooTextFieldOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FooTextFieldOverlay> createState() => _FooTextFieldOverlayState();
}

class _FooTextFieldOverlayState extends State<FooTextFieldOverlay> {
  final controller = TextEditingController(text: '1\n2\nfoo qwerty bar\n4\nblah blah blah qwerty blah blah blah\n6');
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  final forceRepaint = ValueNotifier(0);
  final customPaintKey = GlobalKey();
  late final painter = _FooTextFieldOverlayPainter(
    customPaintKey: customPaintKey,
    repaint: Listenable.merge([scrollController, forceRepaint]),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      context.findRenderObject()?.visitChildren(_visitor);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: CustomPaint(
        key: customPaintKey,
        painter: painter,
        child: TextField(
          controller: controller,
          scrollController: scrollController,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24), // remove to get the defaults
          minLines: null,
          maxLines: 5,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _visitor(RenderObject child) {
    if (child is RenderEditable) {
      painter.setupRenderEditable(child);
      // you could use "scrollController.notifyListeners();" here
      // but the linter complains so:
      forceRepaint.value++;
      return;
    }
    child.visitChildren(_visitor);
  }
}

class _FooTextFieldOverlayPainter extends CustomPainter {
  _FooTextFieldOverlayPainter({required this.customPaintKey, super.repaint});

  GlobalKey customPaintKey;
  RenderEditable? re;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (re case RenderEditable re) {
      final ancestor = customPaintKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject();
      final offset = re.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: ancestor);
      for (final m in 'qwerty'.allMatches(re.plainText)) {
        final boxes = re.getBoxesForSelection(TextSelection(baseOffset: m.start, extentOffset: m.end));
        if (boxes.isNotEmpty) {
          canvas.drawRect(boxes.first.toRect().shift(offset), Paint()..color = Colors.orange.shade200);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_FooTextFieldOverlayPainter oldDelegate) => false;

  void setupRenderEditable(RenderEditable re) {
    print('setting RenderEditable $re');
    this.re = re;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

i just found that `RenderEditable` has two interesting properties: `painter` and `foregroundPainter`

now, if you use `RenderEditable.painter` the code reduces dramatically:

```
class FooTextFieldOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FooTextFieldOverlay> createState() => _FooTextFieldOverlayState();
}

class _FooTextFieldOverlayState extends State<FooTextFieldOverlay> {
  final controller = TextEditingController(text: '1\n2\nfoo qwerty bar\n4\nblah blah blah qwerty blah blah blah\n6');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      context.findRenderObject()?.visitChildren(_visitor);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24), // remove to get the defaults
      minLines: null,
      maxLines: 5,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _visitor(RenderObject child) {
    if (child is RenderEditable) {
      // you could also use child.foregroundPainter if you want to do "foreground painting"
      child.painter = _FooTextFieldOverlayPainter();
      return;
    }
    child.visitChildren(_visitor);
  }
}

class _FooTextFieldOverlayPainter extends RenderEditablePainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size, RenderEditable renderEditable) {
    for (final m in 'qwerty'.allMatches(renderEditable.plainText)) {
      final boxes = renderEditable.getBoxesForSelection(TextSelection(baseOffset: m.start, extentOffset: m.end));
      if (boxes.isNotEmpty) {
        canvas.drawRect(boxes.first.toRect(), Paint()..color = Colors.orange.shade200);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RenderEditablePainter? oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

it seems that when using custom `RenderEditablePainter` if you move the cursor over the area where `_FooTextFieldOverlayPainter` highlights the "qwerty" words the cursor is drawn **behind** so it is hidden by highlighted rectangles

to redraw the cursor on top you would need to use `RenderEditable.getLocalRectForCaret` to get a cursor `Rect` like this:

```
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size, RenderEditable renderEditable) {
    for (final m in 'qwerty'.allMatches(renderEditable.plainText)) {
      final boxes = renderEditable.getBoxesForSelection(TextSelection(baseOffset: m.start, extentOffset: m.end));
      if (boxes.isNotEmpty) {
        canvas.drawRect(boxes.first.toRect(), Paint()..color = Colors.orange.shade200);
      }
    }
    if (renderEditable.showCursor.value && renderEditable.selection != null) {
      final caretRect = renderEditable.getLocalRectForCaret(renderEditable.selection!.base);
      canvas.drawRect(caretRect, Paint()..color = renderEditable.cursorColor ?? Colors.black);
    }
  }
```