How to get a number of line of a text widget?
I tried to get a number of the text widget.
For example, My 2 widgets in the column are the counter widget and the text widget.
The counter widget shows the number of lines of the text widget.
I tried using TextPainter. It can count lines of text widgets but not correctly and it will get incorrect lines when this text widget stays with another widget in the same row.
My example code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CountTextLine(
              text:
                  'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CountTextLine extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  const CountTextLine({super.key, required this.text});

  @override
  State<CountTextLine> createState() => _CountTextLineState();
}

class _CountTextLineState extends State<CountTextLine> {
  int _count = 0;
  late final _textPainter = TextPainter(
    text: TextSpan(text: widget.text),
    maxLines: null,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _updateTextPainter(double width) {
    _textPainter.layout(maxWidth: width);
    _count = _textPainter.computeLineMetrics().length;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        _updateTextPainter(constraints.maxWidth);
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text(_count.toString()),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('Hello My World I Am The Another Widget!!!!!'),
                ),
                Expanded(child: Text(widget.text)),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

You can test this code on dart pad by dragging the screen size to change its screen size.
My example result:

only text widget but not correctly.
You can see this result. This result is not correct.
How to fix this or another way to get the number of text lines? (main required).

have another widget stay with the text widget.
This image shows when my page is complex. The LayoutBuilder was used for the whole page. Yes, I can use the LayoutBuilder for each Text widget to use constraints.maxWidth of Text widget width to get the number of text lines but can we not use the LayoutBuilder for each Text widget that I want to count the number of text? (optional required).



It seems like constraints.maxWidth represents the width of the Row() widget, not the width of the right-side Text. If you remove the left-side text, then _count will be adjusted accordingly.

So, you want to have 2 Text widgets in a Column.
The first text widget will display the number of lines in the second widget. Right?

@Zhentao What I should use instead of the constraints.maxWidth? The _textPainter.layout needs to assign maxWidth to get _textPainter.computeLineMetrics().length.

I just posted my answer, might be helpful@SittiphanSittisak

@IaroslavSiniugin Yes. The first case only has 2 Text widgets and the second case has 2 Text widgets and another widget that stays in the same row as the second Text widget.

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77890325/calculating-substring-position-in-flutter-textfield/77891463#77891463 but for Text widget you should find and use RenderParagraph

@pskink I don't get this. I read this result but did not find a solution to count text lines. I find a solution to find a position of a specific word. How do we apply this?

This makes me clear.
I must use the same TextStyle(ref) and you can use it like Widget function.
However, sometimes the countTextLine is still incorrect because this is an issue. So, the only I can do is wait.
But we can follow this to make job done. This solution concept is to find the countTextLine of text. Then separate this text to the textList that has a length equal to the countTextLine. After that, use a loop to show text from the textList.
UPDATE
After discussing below this post.
We use the TextPainter to count the text lines of the Text widget.
The TextPainter uses the TextSpan widget to count the text lines.
The issue is that some properties are not the same. At this moment we found that only the letterSpacing in the TextStyle property makes this issue. The default TextSyle of the Text widget is not the same as the TextSpan widget.
The solution to fix this has 2 choices.

Use the TextSpan with RichText to display it instead of the Text widget. This solution will always give the correct number of text lines because we count lines using TextSpan. You can see more in this post
Find the default letterSpacing of the TextStyle property of the Text widget to make these styles the same(if the Text widget sets it with a null value). This solution displays this text with the Text widget like normally.

my example code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textWidget = TextWidgetWithCountLineCallback(
      textWidget: const Text('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
      callback: (lines) {
        debugPrint('lines:$lines');
      },
    );

    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: ResponsiveWidth(child: textWidget)));
  }
}

class TextWidgetWithCountLineCallback extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text textWidget;
  final Function(int) callback;
  final TextStyle? textStyle; //optional
  //you can add all property for Text widget to make it complete

  const TextWidgetWithCountLineCallback({super.key, required this.textWidget, required this.callback, this.textStyle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //get TextStyle from textWidget
    final defaultTextStyle = textStyle ?? DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style; //you can change DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style with your custom theme(if you have).
    final textStyleOfTextWidget = textWidget.style ?? defaultTextStyle;

    //assign TextPainter
    final textStyleForPainter = textStyleOfTextWidget.letterSpacing == null ? textStyleOfTextWidget.copyWith(letterSpacing: defaultTextStyle.letterSpacing) : textStyleOfTextWidget;
    final textWidgetForPainter = TextSpan(text: textWidget.data, style: textStyleForPainter);
    final textPainter = TextPainter(text: textWidgetForPainter, maxLines: null, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);

    //use LayoutBuilder to get the current space width(The width will change when the width of the screen/parent widget/widget nearby is changed)
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        //find lines of Text widget
        textPainter.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);
        final countLine = textPainter.computeLineMetrics().length;
        callback(countLine);

        return textWidget;
      },
    );
  }
}

class ResponsiveWidth extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ResponsiveWidth({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  State<ResponsiveWidth> createState() => _ResponsiveWidthState();
}

class _ResponsiveWidthState extends State<ResponsiveWidth> {
  double _scaleValue = 0.5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Slider(
            value: _scaleValue,
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() => _scaleValue = newValue);
            },
          ),
          Container(
            width: _scaleValue * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * _scaleValue,
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Center(child: widget.child),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I adjusted your layout code
return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text('Hello My World I Am The Another Widget!!!!!'),
        ),
        Expanded(child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            _updateTextPainter(constraints.maxWidth);
            return Column(children: [
              Text(_count.toString()),
              Text(widget.text),
            ]);
          },
        )),
      ],
    );

the result looks like this

the _count is correct

I tested but the result was still like the first image result on my post and your solution that uses LayoutBuilder for each text widget that I want to count lines (my post is not clear about this. So I edited it. You can see the description below of each image result.).

@SittiphanSittisak I found an issue and it still open, and I also found a   post might be helpful

Thank you so much. This issue link makes me clear. My question is an issue and it is fixing. The post link is how the problem can be solved. Even though it's not perfect.

It is important that you set the same TextStyle and use the LayoutBuilder directly above your text. As an example:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CountTextLine(
            text1:
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
            text2:
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.',
            text3: 'Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CountTextLine extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text1;
  final String text2;
  final String text3;

  const CountTextLine({
    super.key,
    required this.text1,
    required this.text2,
    required this.text3,
  });

  @override
  State<CountTextLine> createState() => _CountTextLineState();
}

class _CountTextLineState extends State<CountTextLine> {
  late final StreamController<String> _countStream1;
  late final StreamController<String> _countStream2;
  late final StreamController<String> _countStream3;
  late final TextPainter _textPainter;

  TextStyle _getTextStyle = const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.black,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _countStream1 = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
    _countStream2 = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
    _countStream3 = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

    _textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: '',
        style: _getTextStyle,
      ),
      maxLines: null,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _countStream1.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _calculateCount({
    required StreamController<String> stream,
    required double width,
    required String text,
  }) {
    _textPainter.text = TextSpan(
      text: text,
      style: _getTextStyle,
    );
    _textPainter.layout(maxWidth: width, minWidth: width);
    final metrics = _textPainter.computeLineMetrics();

    stream.add(metrics.length.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        _buildFontSizeChanger(),
        _buildTestOne(),
        const Divider(height: 100),
        _buildTestTwo(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFontSizeChanger() {
    return Slider(
      min: 6,
      max: 32,
      value: _getTextStyle.fontSize!,
      onChanged: (value) {
        _getTextStyle = _getTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: value);

        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTestOne() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder<String>(
          stream: _countStream1.stream,
          initialData: '0',
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Chip(
              label: Text(snapshot.data!),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade50,
            );
          },
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: const Text('Hello My World I Am The Another Widget!!!!!'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                _calculateCount(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  stream: _countStream1,
                  text: widget.text1,
                );

                return RichText(text: TextSpan(text: widget.text1, style: _getTextStyle));
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTestTwo() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<String>(
                stream: _countStream2.stream,
                initialData: '0',
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Chip(
                    label: Text(snapshot.data!),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade50,
                  );
                },
              ),
              LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                _calculateCount(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  stream: _countStream2,
                  text: widget.text2,
                );

                return RichText(text: TextSpan(text: widget.text2, style: _getTextStyle));
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: const Text('Hello My World I Am The Another Widget!!!!!'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<String>(
                stream: _countStream3.stream,
                initialData: '0',
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Chip(
                    label: Text(snapshot.data!),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade50,
                  );
                },
              ),
              LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                _calculateCount(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  stream: _countStream3,
                  text: widget.text3,
                );

                return RichText(text: TextSpan(text: widget.text3, style: _getTextStyle));
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


I tried to use TextStyle(fontSize: 16) and it is still not correct.
However, I got the answer about this issue from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78339736/how-to-get-a-number-of-line-of-a-text-widget/78339942?noredirect=1#comment138112604_78339942

I see okay maybe it can happen that sometimes it calculates wrong, but I just updated my example where you can dynamically change the font size and I never had a wrong calculation now. Anyway, maybe different fontFamily will make an error, and I only test it on windows, so let's hope the flutter team will fix this issue soon ;)

Yes, I hope they will fix it soon. Ps. I don't know why I got this issue. I use Windows 10 and test this on DartPad. I got this issue when I changed the text style to TextStyle _getTextStyle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 16);. is what I got. Maybe some environments are not the same.

Yeah, some environments may be different. But just to make sure that when you change the TextStyle you didn't remove wordSpacing: 1 and letterSpacing: 0 right? Because I don't know why, but when we don't set it to these values, it also doesn't work in my tests.

No, I removed these. After I tried to test these properties. I found that it will work when we set the letterSpacing (I tried with letterSpacing: 0) but the text UI between remove and not remove this letterSpacing: 0 is different.
Maybe this is another solution to fix this (if not serious about UI)(but I don't know why it can fix).

Ah, I got it, why we need to set the letterSpacing. I checked the code from Flutter and saw it render Text and TextSpan with different letterSpacing when we don't set by ourselves a value. I just replace each Text with RichText(text: TextSpan(text: widget.text1, style: _getTextStyle)) and everything works fine even without setting letterSpacing. The only thing which I needed to do was to set a text color in the style to black. The problem before was I had in the UI the Text widget but in the TextPainter it renders a TextSpan which made this problem.

Yeah, good idea to use the TextSpan to count the lines and display this text. I found another solution too. I use the default TextStyle of the Text widget for the TextSpan. See more at the update at https://stackoverflow.com/a/78341140/17798537
