# How to use multi font families for multi language at same time?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

How to use multi Font Family for multi language at same time?
just like CSS

I have problem when I use some font family of different language, When I write in English English font become bad
so I need some thing like CSS make me use font family for English and another font family for different language works together at same time

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information's.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57846261/13313941) is a great explanation for your problem

Comment: i can't use RichText in input fields and I don't know when I get the data from server will contains an English words or not, this way will be good with static texts only.