# How to mention username in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield, mention

I want to implement the feature mention for flutter. When the user type @ and put some username behind it, it will trigger the mention list load from api (This part I already handle), the point is when the user choose the username from list it will autocomplete and replace the @ with the username (Username not userid, the username is not unique) and style the text to blue.
I already try this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mentions, this package only work for the userid.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839668/how-to-change-color-of-particular-text-in-a-text-field-dynamically

Comment: @khoa Le, any solution you want to share?

Comment: any solution for this?